# Heap corruption when attempting to print

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-management, printing, gdi

I've been working on a native Unity plugin that will allow a user to print something (text at the moment) to the default printer on Windows.

My (**EDIT: OLD**) code is as follows for printing text:

```
bool PrintText(const char* pText, int pTextWidth, int pTextHeight, const char* pPrinterName) {
        LPCSTR szDriver = (LPCSTR)"WINSPOOL";
        TCHAR   szPrinter[256];
        DWORD   cchBuffer = 255;
        HDC     hdcPrint = NULL;
        HDC     hdcPrintImg = NULL;
        HANDLE  hPrinter = NULL;
        PRINTER_INFO_2  *pPrinterData;
        BYTE    pdBuffer[16384];
        BOOL    bReturn = FALSE;
        LPCSTR  documentFilename = "PrintTest";
        LPCSTR  documentText = (LPCSTR)pText;
        DWORD   cbBuf = sizeof(pdBuffer);
        DWORD   cbNeeded = 0;
        pPrinterData = (PRINTER_INFO_2 *)&pdBuffer[0];

        bReturn = GetDefaultPrinter(szPrinter, &cchBuffer);

        if (bReturn) {
            bReturn = OpenPrinter((LPSTR)pPrinterName, &hPrinter, NULL);
        }

        if (bReturn) {
            bReturn = GetPrinter(hPrinter, 2, &pdBuffer[0], cbBuf, &cbNeeded);
            ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
        }

        if (bReturn) {
            hdcPrint = CreateDC(szDriver, (LPSTR)pPrinterName, pPrinterData->pPortName, NULL);
        }

        if (hdcPrint) {
            Escape(hdcPrint, STARTDOC, 8, documentFilename, NULL);
            TextOut(hdcPrint, pTextWidth, pTextHeight, documentText, strlen((const char*)documentText));
            Escape(hdcPrint, NEWFRAME, 0, NULL, NULL);
            Escape(hdcPrint, ENDDOC, 0, NULL, NULL);

            DeleteDC(hdcPrint);
        }
        return bReturn;
    }
```

This will send the document to the print spooler and successfully print, however, I get a breakpoint triggered in VS saying that a heap has been corrupted.

I'm very new to C++ and unmanaged languages in general so any pointers (ha!) will be much appreciated :)

EDIT:
A person at work helped pinpoint the problems. 
The bare minimum code to print text to a printer:

```
bool PrintText(char* inputText, int positionX, int positionY, char* printerName)
{
    HDC     printerDeviceContext = NULL;
    HANDLE  printerHandle = NULL;
    BOOL    bReturn = FALSE;
    LPCSTR  documentFilename = "PrintTest";
    LPCSTR  documentText = (LPCSTR)inputText;
    DWORD   buffer;
    DWORD   bytesRequired;

    bReturn = OpenPrinter((LPSTR)printerName, &printerHandle, NULL);

    GetPrinter(printerHandle, 2, NULL, 0, &buffer);
    BYTE* printerBuffer = new BYTE[buffer]; //allocate buffer
    bReturn = GetPrinter(printerHandle, 2, printerBuffer, buffer, &bytesRequired);

    ClosePrinter(printerHandle);

    printerDeviceContext = CreateDC(NULL, printerName, NULL, NULL);

    if (printerDeviceContext)
    {
        Escape(printerDeviceContext, STARTDOC, 8, documentFilename, NULL);
        TextOut(printerDeviceContext, positionX, positionY, documentText, strlen((char*)documentText));
        Escape(printerDeviceContext, NEWFRAME, 0, NULL, NULL);
        Escape(printerDeviceContext, ENDDOC, 0, NULL, NULL);

        DeleteDC(printerDeviceContext);
    }

    delete[] printerBuffer; //free buffer

    return bReturn;
}
```

Comment: Mixing `char` and `TCHAR` is asking for trouble. Ditch both, and use `wchar_t` throughout, together with the explicit Unicode versions of the Windows APIs (e.g. `GetDefaultPrinterW`).

Comment: Messages about heap corruption show up when the memory manager discovers them, which isn't necessarily anywhere near where they were caused.

Comment: @IInspectable, I agree that mixing `char` and `TCHAR` is a bad idea, but so is hardcoding the Unicode APIs. Just make everything `TCHAR` and it will all compile and work perfectly in both 32- and 64-bit builds.

Comment: @CareyGregory: Based on what rationale is it a *"bad idea"* to hardcode the only API you'll ever be using (i.e. Unicode)? On the contrary, it removes one parameter from your testing matrix. This is completely unrelated to 32/64-bit.

Comment: @IInspectable I didn't see where the OP said would he never want to support ASCII, so why lock yourself into Unicode-only builds when the ability to build for either ASCII or Unicode is provided for free? If you're truly not going to use one or the other then it can disappear from the testing matrix. Meanwhile, you're using all the "normal" Win32 function names and retain the ability to change your mind in the future. (Obviously I meant to say ASCII and Unicode, not 32- and 64-bit in my previous comment.)

Comment: @CareyGregory: I guess, you have to be a US-ian to perceive Unicode as a *"lock-in"*. You also have to be a US-ian to conclude, that an MBCS build (there is no ASCII API) would *"work perfectly"*. It won't. MBCS doesn't come for free either: For every API call the system has to translate character strings back and forth. Using the codepage that happens to be currently active on a given thread. In all, there is **nothing** to be gained from using MBCS. Unless you really, **REALLY** need to support 16-bit Windows.

Comment: @IInspectable Sigh...I didn't mean to imply that anything was free performance-wise. Rarely is anything free in that arena. I meant that the provision for supporting both MBCS (pedantic given the "A" appended to function names) and Unicode transparently is already present in the Win32 API. And that has absolutely nothing to do with Win16 or being from the US. There are many commercial apps out there that run only on modern Windows that still get built using the non-Unicode API. I envy people who work only on brand new code who can ignore several decades of history but I don't have that luxury.

Comment: @CareyGregory: There is no built-in provision that hides character encodings **transparently**. While `TCHAR` enables your code to compile for MBCS and Unicode settings, it does not imply that it will work with either encoding. It usually won't. Irrespective of the code base you are working on, it is generally advisable to explicitly use the Unicode APIs. Should you need to convert between encodings, there are numerous [conversion macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx) available. This beats having the system do the conversions for you, and hoping for the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually don't see any direct issues which could result in heap corruption.

However there are a couple of other issues in the code above:

1. The third parameter of CreateDC should be NULL.
2. the second param for CreateDC should not be cast to LPSTR!!! (it's not a problem here, since the method excpects a LPCSTR anyway, but still: casting away a const is only necessary in very rare cases of incorrectly written libraries... Using it always has the risk of undefined behavior).
3. General: Only do casts if it is necessary. (in most cases in your code, it actually isn't)
4. Never allocate 16k memory on the stack (`BYTE pdBuffer[16384]`): Basically you should call GetPrinter() twice: once without providing a buffer. This call will fail, but it will return the size of the buffer which is actually required. Then allocate a buffer for that size and provide it to the second call.

Edit:
4 should actually look somewhat like this:

```
GetPrinter(hPrinter, 2, NULL, 0, &cbNeeded);
BYTE* pBuffer = new BYTE[cbNeeded]; //allocate buffer
bReturn = GetPrinter(hPrinter, 2, pBuffer, cbNeeded, &cbActual);

// do something with pBuffer

delete[] pBuffer; //free buffer
```

Edit 2:
Basically there are three things that can go wrong:

- You try to free memory which has already been freed

  `delete pObject;
   //some code
   delete pObject;`
- You try to use memory which has already been freed

  `delete pObject;
   pObject->use();`
- You have a buffer overflow on the heap somewhere

  `pBuffer = new BYTES[3]
   memcpy(pBuffer, pSomeMemory, 100); //copy 100 bytes into a 3 byte buffer
   delete[] pBuffer;`

Chances are very high that the actual error is in some other part of your code.

Comment: excuse my Ignorance, but for point 4. how would I restructure my code to do this? Do I just pass all `NULL` to the 1st GetPrinter() call?
And how do I declare and pass the size into my `pdBuffer`?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm still getting heap corruption break around the OpenPrinter call (and it sometimes happens slightly before or after this). Still not entirely sure what's going on. Are my types OK?